# Внешний ключ в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

POJO

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "allOpers", query = "SELECT o FROM Opers o")
public class Opers {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String name;
private String surname;
@ManyToOne
private Filials filials;

public Opers() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Opers(int id, String name, String surname, Filials filials) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.filials = filials;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public Filials getFilials() {
    return filials;
}

public void setFilials(Filials filials) {
    this.filials = filials;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Opers [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", surname=" + surname + ", filials=" + filials + "]";
}

}
```

И есть страница

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Opers</title>
</head>
<body>
<sf:form modelAttribute="opers"
    action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/opers"
    method="GET">
    <table border="1" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Surname</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${Opers}" var="op">
            <tr>
                <td>${op.id}</td>
                <td>${op.name}</td>
                <td>${op.surname}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</sf:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Контроллер

```
@Controller
public class OperController {
@Autowired
private OperService operService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/opers/{filialId}", method =
RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getOpers(@PathVariable("filialId") int filialId) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("opers");
    model.addObject("opers", operService.getOperByFilialId(filialId));
    return model;
}
}
```

При вызове страницы из другой страницы

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/insert">
    <table border="1" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Adress</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${filials}" var="fil">
            <tr>
                <td>${fil.id}</td>
                <td><a
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/opers/${fil.id}">${fil.name
</a></td>
                <td>${fil.adress}</td>
                <td><a
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/update/${fil.id}">Update</a
</td>
                <td><a
                    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/delete
id=${fil.id}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="insert" name="btnInsert" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Мне не выводит данные, которые связаны по внешнему ключу с другой таблицей, то есть, контроллер не работает.

**Обновление**

sql код показывает, что Hibernate:

```
select opers0_.id as id1_1_0_, opers0_.filials_id as filials_4_1_0_, opers0_.name as name2_1_0_, opers0_.surname as surname3_1_0_, filials1_.id as id1_0_1_, filials1_.adress as adress2_0_1_, filials1_.name as name3_0_1_ from Opers opers0_ left outer join Filials filials1_ on opers0_.filials_id=filials1_.id where opers0_.id=?
```

В методе я писал чтоб он искал по `filial_id`.

Отдельно весь список выводит нормально, insert, update, delete делает нормально. Только вывод значений связанных с другой таблицей, он не выводит.

Создав обычный класс, чтоб проверить работу метода

```
public class TestApp {
    @ Autowired
    static OperService operService;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Opers opers = operService.getOperByFilialId(2);
        System.out.println(opers);
    }
}
```

На выходе у меня дает

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   az.nikoil.test.TestApp.main(TestApp.java:17)

Вот код метода

```
@ Override
@ Transactional
public Opers getOperByFilialId(int filialId) {
    return operDAO.getOperByFilialId(filialId);
 }
```

Это operDAOImpl

```
@Repository
public class OperDAOImpl extends AbstractSessionFactory implements
OperDAO {
@Override
public void insert(Opers oper) {
    getSession().save(oper);
}

@Override
public void update(Opers oper) {
    getSession().update(oper);
}

@Override
public void delete(int operId) {
    getSession().delete(getOper(operId));
}

@Override
public Opers getOper(int operId) {
    return (Opers) getSession().get(Opers.class, operId);
}

@Override
public Opers getOperByFilialId(int filialId) {
    return (Opers) getSession().get(Opers.class, filialId);
}

@Override
public List<Opers> getAllOpers() {
    return getSession().getNamedQuery("allOpers").list();
}
}
```

а это operServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class OperServiceImpl implements OperService {
@Autowired
private OperDAO operDAO;

@Override
@Transactional
public void insert(Opers oper) {
    operDAO.insert(oper);

}

@Override
@Transactional
public void update(Opers oper) {
    operDAO.update(oper);

}

@Override
@Transactional
public void delete(int operId) {
    operDAO.delete(operId);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public Opers getOper(int operId) {
    return operDAO.getOper(operId);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public Opers getOperByFilialId(int filialId) {
    return operDAO.getOperByFilialId(filialId);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public List<Opers> getAllOpers() {
    return operDAO.getAllOpers();
}
}
```

Comment: hibernate хоть как нибудь отписывается?

Comment: @Farik013 Вы не понимаете как `@Autowired` работает. Тестовый класс надо брать из контекста Spring.

Comment: @Farik013 Ваш SQL выбирает один `Opers` вместе с одним `Filials`. Где заполнение `${filials}` в контроллере? И почему Вы свой `OperService` и  `operDAO` не показываете?

Comment: @v.ladynev поставил "OperService" и "OperService"

Comment: @Farik013 Вы интерфейсы добавили. А реализация? И где `${filials}` в контроллере заполняется?

Comment: @v.ladynev реализацию поставил, а '${filials}' в конроллере не заполняется.

Comment: @Farik013 Так надо же заполнять, Вы к этой коллекции на JSP обращаетесь. И надо еще добавить метод получения `filials` в `OperService`.

Comment: @v.ladynev 'filials' я получаю на другой странице. Там все нормально выводится у меня, при переходе с той страницы, я по URL отправляю id filial-a и по этому id хочу получить opers. Но в jsp выводится пустая таблица.
    '<c:forEach items="${opers}" var="op">
    <tr>
     <td>${op.id}</td>
     <td>${op.name}</td>
     <td>${op.surname}</td>
    </tr>
   </c:forEach>'

Comment: @Farik013 В исходнике у вас `${Opers}` с большой буквы и это один объект, ане список. Непонятно, почему Вы его с помощью `forEach` выводите.

Comment: @v.ladynev когда я пишу '${opers}' у меня выходит 'javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;'